# password based authentication for internet

Tags: internet, proxy

I would like to implement a password based authentication for all the users to access the internet from my network and then log the data usages by each user. how can I do this?

Comment: The term for the product you are looking for is a "[Captive Portal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on your router's platform you could use an off-the-shelve product like Squid or Microsoft's ISA server.

There is a description on configuring Squid with authentication on [this page](http://www.daveshuck.com/2008/01/10/configuring-squid-proxy-server-to-require-user-authentication/). You can then use [squint](http://www.ledge.co.za/software/squint/index.php) to analyze the log files for usage figures.

If your router cannot run a proxy, you could set up NAT rules to forward all traffic to an external proxy server. [example](http://www.danscourses.com/Linux-Fundamentals/route-nat-and-transparent-proxy-with-centos-linux.html)